# navbar is vertical instead of horizontal

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="navigation">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a></li>
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/browse">Browse</a></li>
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/create">Create</a></li>
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/review">Review</a></li>
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/help">Help</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline">
         <a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>
         <div id="my-signin2">
            <!-- google oauth stuff -->
         </div>
      </form>
   </nav>
</div>
```

Why does this show a vertical list instead of a horizontal one?

Comment: @jeh ta-da. I don't know, I just used some bootstrap cdn. The code and problem are now reproducible in a jsfiddle/any environment via just copy+paste.

Comment: I think you are mixing bootstrap 3 and 4. Upgrading from 3 to 4 is not that simple.  Markup and classes need to be updated. Eg. there is no `navbar-default` class in bootstrap 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed the `navbar-nav` class and it's horizontal again. My best guess is that the navbar-nav class has some css associated with it that was overwriting the `navbar-default` styles.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="navigation">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <ul class="nav">
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a></li>
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/browse">Browse</a></li>
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/create">Create</a></li>
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/review">Review</a></li>
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/help">Help</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline">
         <a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>
         <div id="my-signin2">
            <!-- google oauth stuff -->
         </div>
      </form>
   </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of just removing Bootstrap's navbar-nav from ul (as of writing it contains five properties), in my custom CSS I added the class and overrode flex-direction with flex-direction: row !important. I imagine keeping the other four properties of the class will get more predictable results and cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include Jquery `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` and make sure to wrap your navbar ul in a container-fluid as demonstrated. This way when resized it will be responsive and get vertically aligned for small viewports :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="navigation">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a></li>
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/browse">Browse</a></li>
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/create">Create</a></li>
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/review">Review</a></li>
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/help">Help</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline">
         <a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>
         <div id="my-signin2">
            <!-- google oauth stuff -->
         </div>
      </form>
      </div>
   </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to view it at full screen.

Comment: Bootstrap is responsive by default, so the preview you see here is vertical, but it turns horizontal once the page is wide enough

Answer (score 0):

You can Remove the Background.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu-outer">
<div id="table">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default horizontal-list">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a></li>
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/browse">Browse</a></li>
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/create">Create</a></li>
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/review">Review</a></li>
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/help">Help</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline">
         <a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>
         <div id="my-signin2">
            <!-- google oauth stuff -->
         </div>
      </form>
   </nav>
</div>
</div>

<style>
    #menu-outer {
    height: 84px;
    background: url(images/bar-bg.jpg) repeat-x;
}

.table {
    display: table;   /* Allow the centering to work */
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul#horizontal-list {
    min-width: 696px;
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 20px;
    }
    ul#horizontal-list li {
        display: inline;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

From what I see your issue is that lists are lists, ul and li will make vertical lists.  If you want horizontal you need some css, or some style.

Try adding something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul li {
    display:inline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-    beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-    beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="navigation">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a></li>
     <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/browse">Browse</a></li>
     <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/create">Create</a></li>
     <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/review">Review</a></li>
     <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/help">Help</a></li>
  </ul>
  <form class="form-inline">
     <a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>
     <div id="my-signin2">
        <!-- google oauth stuff -->
     </div>
  </form>
  </nav>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```